# SSRS Fill Expression With Nested IIF's Won't Display Colors Properly

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am attempting to make the fill color of the entire row of cells red if a certain values are NULL so I am applying the expression to all cells in the row. The cells that I am applying the fill expression won't necessarily include the field at the top level. I'm finding that the expression I am using is leaving the row white even though my final else is blue. I am also getting the warning "[rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The BackgroundColor expression for the text box  contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format". Hope this makes sense. See example below:

Table Columns: Account1, Account2, Account3

Fill Expression applied to all 3 columns:

```
=IIF(Fields!Account1.Value = "", "Red", IIF(Fields!Account2.Value = "", "Red", "Blue"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `IsNothing` instead of checking for an empty string. An empty string is something whereas NULL is unknown and needs to be handled differently.

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Account1.Value), "Red", 
    IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Account2.Value), "Red", "Blue"))
```